# I am making the home page and the login page shows a problem with the entry buttons

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hoKKa.png)

This error appears on more than one page, knowing that I have import for all libraries

Comment: Why you return Background? You have to return Scaffold

Comment: You should provide more information about what the actual problem is and what you've tried to solve the problem. Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @Vaidarbhi Because every page has a different background

Comment: Can you please provide your code snippet at here?

Answer (score 1):

Background is not a flutter widget. Instead return a widget like container with background color property in decoration attribute. There are various other ways to change the background. But this is one of the way:

```
 return Container(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 15, right: 15),
      margin: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 5, right: 5),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: Colors.grey,
      ),
       child: ...
        add all your child widgets here
      )
```

Or you can return a scaffold

```
return Scaffold(
    backgroundColor: Colors.red,
...)
```